# Can you $unwind several fields at once in MongoDB Compass?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I am doing aggregation on several documents that have a common `id` field using MongoDB Compass. Firstly I tried the following way:

```
db.data.aggregate([
$group : {
_id : "$id",
"id" : {$first : "$id"},
"email" : {$first : "$email"},
...
}])
```

However, the problem with this solution is that for some of the fields I was getting `null` instead of the real data. I figured out that it was caused by the `$first` operation and to solve that issue instead of `$first` I used the `$addToSet` operation.
So the code above became:

```
 db.data.aggregate([
    $group : {
    _id : "$id",
    "id" : {$addToSet : "$id"},
    "email" : {$addToSet : "$email"},
    ...
    }])
```

After this, I am not missing any data and everything aggregates just fine. Now the issue is that for each field the corresponding value is an array of just one string. For example, after using `$addToSet` I am getting the following result:

```
{
"id" : "001",
"email" : Array(0: "asdf@gmail.com"),
"title" : Array(0: "title1")
...
}
```

I learned about the `$unwind` operation that helps me to collapse the array and get that one element but ***I wonder if there is a way to "unwind" all elements at once,*** as now I have to do the `unwind` stage for each key-value pair one by one which is time-consuming.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. `$unwind` by definition receives a single field path.

What you can do that will be the easiest is use `arrayElemAt` under the assumption there is a single value for a group per field ( as shown by your sample ). like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      "id": {
        "$addToSet": "$id"
      },
      "email": {
        $addToSet: "$email"
      },
      "title": {
        $addToSet: "$title"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      id: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$id",
          0
        ]
      },
      email: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$email",
          0
        ]
      },
      title: {
        "$arrayElemAt": [
          "$title",
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RayIyLdDzBT)

Answer (score 0):

use [$concatArrays](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/) and then unwind it

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.